# Add date of first day of week to date dimension

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

I want to add a column to my date dimension that contains the date of the first day of that week. here's a piece of what it looks like

```
CalendarDate    DayOfWeekNumber DayKey  DayOfWeekName   WeekNumber
 1996-01-01     2      19960101     MONDAY           1
  1996-01-02    3   19960102    TUESDAY             1
  1996-01-03    4   19960103    WEDNESDAY          1
  1996-01-04    5   19960104    THURSDAY           1
  1996-01-05    6   19960105    FRIDAY             1
  1996-01-06    7   19960106    SATURDAY           1
  1996-01-07    1   19960107    SUNDAY             1
  1996-01-08    2   19960108    MONDAY             2
  1996-01-09    3   19960109    TUESDAY            2
  1996-01-10    4   19960110    WEDNESDAY          2
  1996-01-11    5   19960111    THURSDAY           2
  1996-01-12    6   19960112    FRIDAY             2
  1996-01-13    7   19960113    SATURDAY           2
  1996-01-14    1   19960114    SUNDAY             2
```

So basically i would want a column `WeekStartDate` that, for each `WeekNumber` would have the `CalendarDate` of the first dayOfWeekNumber (dayOfWeekNumber =1)

It would look like

```
CalendarDate    DayOfWeekNumber DayKey  DayOfWeekName   WeekNumber   WeekStart
 1996-01-01     2      19960101     MONDAY           1             1996-01-01
  1996-01-02    3   19960102    TUESDAY             1              1996-01-01
  1996-01-03    4   19960103    WEDNESDAY          1               1996-01-01
  1996-01-04    5   19960104    THURSDAY           1               "
  1996-01-05    6   19960105    FRIDAY             1               "
  1996-01-06    7   19960106    SATURDAY           1               "
  1996-01-07    1   19960107    SUNDAY             1               "
  1996-01-08    2   19960108    MONDAY             2               1996-01-08
  1996-01-09    3   19960109    TUESDAY            2               "
  1996-01-10    4   19960110    WEDNESDAY          2               "
  1996-01-11    5   19960111    THURSDAY           2               "
  1996-01-12    6   19960112    FRIDAY             2
  1996-01-13    7   19960113    SATURDAY           2
  1996-01-14    1   19960114    SUNDAY             2
```

so something like

`update myTable set WeekStartDate = CalendarDate where dayofweeknumber=2 (monday) for each weeknumber` (pseudocode, i know that's not what literally what i want it to do).

Thanks for suggestions. Pretty sure I need to window on weeknumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  C
SET     WeekStartDate = week_start
FROM
(
    select  *, week_start = min(CalendarDate) 
                            over (partition by year(CalendarDate), WeekNumber)
    from    Calendar
) AS C
```